# C# - Clicking on buttons via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, selenium, phantomjs

I had the following situation and problem with C# but didn't found a real solution online.

A program should click on a button on a particular page. It can be done in 2 different ways.
This page includes external javascript that I want to execute.
So clicking a button not via [element].InvokeMember("click")
but with executing via [webBrowser].InvokeScript([...])

But it isn't working.

I couldn't determine whether it opens another window (cause the browser is unvisible in the background).

So: I ask now - Is there a way to determine this or am I doing something wrong D:?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you =)!

My method to execute the javascript (Browser is a System.Windows.Controls object) - It should buy an item in the steamcommunity market - but it doesn't:

```
 browser.Navigate([page]);
 browser.InvokeScript("method", new object[] { "'[String]'", "'" + [Integer] + "'", [Integer], "'[Integer]'", "'" + [Integer] + "'" });
```

/

```
 browser.Navigate("http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/PP-Bizon%20%7C%20Sand%20Dashed%20%28Field-Tested%29");
 browser.LoadCompleted += webBrowser_PageLoaded;
```

And in webBrowser_PageLoaded:

```
 browser.InvokeScript("BuyMarketListing", new object[] { "'listing'", "'" + listingid + "'", 730, "'2'", "'" + assetid + "'" });
```

UPDATE 1:
http://www.seleniumhq.org/ this opens a new window. Can this be done in the background without opening a new one? And: I don't get cookies working =/

UPDATE 2:
Solving the window problem with Selenium+PhantomJS

Now there is still the problem that I cannot react to the new input form that opens.
+
Problem2: Cookies still don't work

Comment: Please post the code you have tried and the code for the button. Also have you tried displaying something if the button was clicked ?

Comment: huh? you couldn't determine if clicking a button opens another window?

Comment: Did it @deathismyfriend =)!

Comment: are you asking if browser.navigate() opens a new window or not?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but it seems you are doing some automatic UI testing by mimic button clicking. There's a tool called selenium does the automatic UI testing and it's relatively easy to work with.

http://www.seleniumhq.org/

Comment: That seems interesting. Thanks for your answer =)! - I will look into it.